# Make Imported Library Internal

Tags: c#, .net

I have a DB repository library which I import to another library project.
The DB library contain public models which I don't want it to be exposed to other projects that use the second library
is there's any trick that would help me do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with `public` classes. But if your assemblies are strongly signed then you could use the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute and make those classes `internal`. The idea of this attribute is that you can place it in your DB library assembly and include a list of other assemblies that will *see* `internal` classes as if they were public.